# Why char [] as a static

Tags: c

Please tell me: Why `char []` as a static in the code below (all code through this link: cpp.sh/7krd3)? I can't understand reason.

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
     {
     static char szAppName[] = "HelloWin" ;
     HWND        hwnd ;
     MSG         msg ;
     WNDCLASSEX  wndclass ;

     //...
```

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov it is just convention as variable will have a static storage instead of automatic.

Comment: With the code as shown, it makes no difference.   It *might* make a difference if the program launches threads AND at least one of those threads continues executing and somehow access `szAppName` after `WinMain()` has returned.    That occurrence is unlikely in practice, as it is often easier to set up the program and threads to prevent it (e.g. `WinMain()` waits on the other threads, and only returns when all other threads have completed).    However, the most likely reason is that the programmer introduced the `static` keyword without thought - programmers are like that, too often.

Comment: @Peter — one other advantage of the static variable is that the initialization is done before the function is called, rather than as active copying when it is called. The difference isn’t likely to be measurable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ....   I'm not sure something that contributes no measurable difference represents an advantage.   Practically `WinMain()` is a (windows-specific) program entry point, so no code in the program (other than the startup code) will be able to access the variable before `WinMain()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to make it a static (global) variable. The Windows API does not specify this requirement anywhere. The Windows API seems to just copy the name as required and internally creates an atom for it.

The following lines are taken from the `generic.c` example from the 1994 Windows 3.1 development kit:

```
BOOL InitApplication(hInstance)
HANDLE hInstance;
{
    WNDCLASS  wc;
    /*...*/
    wc.lpszClassName = "GenericWClass"; /* Name used in call to CreateWindow. */
    return (RegisterClass(&wc));
}
```

The class name here is a read-only literal string (if read-only segments existed in 1994).

Answer (score -1):

`szAppName` has to have lifetime same as entire program. Pointer to this variable is passed and used even when the WinMain returns. Otherwise it will be the Undefined Behavior.

Comment: The question is why is it not a string literal - does this need to be modified? Or is it because of some stupid C++ compatibility.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala he asked: *Why char [] as a **static** in the code below*

Comment: well, yes, that is true, a string literal would be static too, but sometimes newbies don't know how to ask the right question :D

Comment: Probably literal is OK if used with the TEXT macro. Otherwise `const char []` has to be used.  I think it is because of the unicode interpretation of the literals. One of the Windows secrets.

Comment: It is related to its lifetime. Automatic variables exist only in the scope where they were defined and any references become invalid when program exits this scope

Comment: I find no information in the Windows API that `szClassName` must be a global variable with life-time exceeding `WinMain`. It can be an automatic variable in all circumstances. Note that `WinMain` includes the message loop and is active during the lifetime of the program. The Windows API copies the name and it can be released after the calls to `RegisterClass` and `CreateWindow`.